# What is the purpose of Tiling layer in Caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

What is the purpose of the Tiling layer in Caffe? It seems it is a form of reshaping the input, however I'm wondering how exactly it works and where it could be applied?

This is the source code:

```
template <typename Dtype>
void TilingLayer<Dtype>::LayerSetUp(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom,
    const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {
  TilingParameter tiling_param = this->layer_param_.tiling_param();
  tile_dim_ = tiling_param.tile_dim();
  tile_dim_sq_ = tile_dim_ * tile_dim_;
  CHECK(tile_dim_) << "tile_dim must be specified.";
  CHECK_GT(tile_dim_, 0) << "tile_dim must be positive.";
}


template <typename Dtype> void TilingLayer<Dtype>::Reshape(const 
vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom,
    const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {   
CHECK_EQ(top.size(), 1);   
input_channels_ = bottom[0]->channels();   
input_height_ = bottom[0]->height();   
input_width_ = bottom[0]->width();   
output_channels_ = bottom[0]->channels() / tile_dim_sq_;   
output_width_ = input_width_ * tile_dim_;
output_height_ = input_height_ * tile_dim_;   
count_per_output_map_ = output_width_ * output_height_;   
count_per_input_map_ = input_width_ * input_height_; 
CHECK_EQ(0, input_channels_ % tile_dim_sq_)
      << "The number of input channels for tiling layer must be multiples "
      << "of the tile_dim.";   top[0]->Reshape(bottom[0]->num(), 
input_channels_ / tile_dim_sq_,
  input_height_ * tile_dim_, input_width_ * tile_dim_); }
```

Answer (score 2):

tiling layer is different from tile layer, tiling layer is like reshape, but tile layer is like repmat.

=============== edit to add more details ==========
For tile layer, as shown in the source code, https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/tile_layer.cpp

```
Dtype* top_data = top[0]->mutable_cpu_data();
  for (int i = 0; i < outer_dim_; ++i) {
    for (int t = 0; t < tiles_; ++t) {
      caffe_copy(inner_dim_, bottom_data, top_data);
      top_data += inner_dim_;
    }
    bottom_data += inner_dim_;
  }
```

the top data is just tiles_ times of input data, with N*C*H*W and tile_dim = 8, you get blob with shape N*C*(H*8)*(W*8)
but for tiling layer, it flatten the layer, for example you have N*C*H*W blob, and tiling_dim=8, then after tiling layer, the count doesn't change, but you get blob with shape  N*(C/64)*(H*8)*(W*8).

Comment: Good point, though more elaborate answer would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[`"Tile"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/tile.html) layer in caffe implements similar operation to numpy's [`tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html), or Matlab's [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) functions: it copies the content of an array along a specified dimension.

For example, suppose you have a 2D "attention" (or "saliency") map, and you want to weigh the features according to these weights: give more weight to "salinet" regions and less to non "salient" regions. One way to achieve that is to multiply (element-wise) the 3D feature map by the 2D saliency map. To do so you need to `"Tile"` the saliency map along the channel dimension (from 2D to 3D) and then to apply `"Eltwise"` layer.

Comment: Do Tiling layer and Tile layer do the same job?

Comment: @cerebrou can you link to the source of the code you posted?